# How can I access the 'GitHub for Mac' command-line utility from the terminal?

Tags: git, osx-lion, github-for-mac

I recently installed GitHub for Mac, the graphical Git client from GitHub, and also the command-line utility from its menu, shown below:

[image: GitHub for Mac menu]

I was notified the command-line utility had been installed in `/usr/local/github`, but when I checked it had actually been put in `/usr/local/bin/github` - details shown below:

[image: Terminal results]

When I try to run `git` I get `-bash: git: command not found`, so I added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to `~/.profile` thinking it would solve the issue, but it hasn't - all that seems to be different is I can now start GitHub for Mac from the terminal by typing `github`.

Please could someone with more knowledge explain what's happening here?

Comment: What's in that github folder?

Comment: Hi Thomas, it's not a directory. I think it's a symbolic link to a file inside of the GitHub.app(?) Check the second screenshot.

Comment: What happens if you try to directly execute the file that is sym linked?

Comment: Scot, it starts GitHub for Mac - the graphical client - which is confusing, considering it says it's linked to `github_cli`.

Comment: If you look at that screenshot, there is a symlink from `github` to the command line thing. So why do you expect `git` to work on the command line? That being said, GitHub for Mac uses gitlib, a C library and as such is not dependent on the actual Git command line and does not ship with it. You need to install it separately.

Comment: You now have another option to install Git CLI (Command-Line Interface). See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "GitHub for Mac" command-line utility is just a tool for launching "GitHub for Mac" in the current directory.

To install the `git` command line tool use either [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (`brew install git`) or the [Git for OS X](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-osx-installer) installer.

Comment: The latest version (176) does install git for use on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

From May 2013, you now have a different option:

See "[Installing Git from GitHub for Mac](https://github.com/blog/1510-installing-git-from-github-for-mac)"

> you can now easily install Git for use on the command line, without needing to download any separate packages.
>   And whenever we update the version of Git included with GitHub for Mac, you'll get the changes automatically – no work required on your part!
>
> you may notice some changes to the Preferences window.
>   On the newly renamed "`Advanced`" tab, simply click "`Install Command Line Tools`".

[image: click install]

> You'll be prompted for an administrator password so that Git can be installed into `/usr/local/bin`, and then you should very shortly see that it succeeded:

[image]