# Git setup, terminal returning : command not found

Tags: git, terminal

I'm trying to setup Git on my computer and now I'm supposed to write in this command to terminal: `$ git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"` but it is answering: -bash: $: command not found. I dont get any of this, can someone please help me?

Comment: What's your OS? How did you install Git? If you run `which git` in Bash, what's the output?

Answer (score 9):

Take out the `$` at the start; `$` is just the normal notation that people write to show that it's a terminal command.

The real command is:

```
git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"
```

Since `git` isn't working and you're running Github for Mac, you can install the command line tools through the Github Preferences in the Advanced tab.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but it is still responding me with: -bash: git: command not found

Comment: In that case you also don't appear to have `git` installed, you can find some installers on the Git site: http://git-scm.com/download/

Comment: Or it's installed, but not in your `$PATH`.

Comment: No, Github is a Git hosting website that can host your Git repositories. Git is a program that you can use on your computer to push to Github remote repositories or Bitbucket remote repositories, etc.

Comment: @Delal, no but kinda. GitHub is an online service that provides Git hosting. In that context they're completely different. But if you've installed the GitHub *program* for Windows or OSX (which is still different from Git), then you should *also* have a proper `git` command line version that would have been installed alongside it.

Comment: @Chris, if i write echo PATH, I can't see git anywhere.

Comment: What OS, and how did you install git?

Comment: @Delal, you wouldn't necessarily see it directly in `$PATH` (for example if your `git` binary lives at `/usr/bin/git` you'd only see `/usr/bin`. What's your OS, and how did you install Git?

Comment: I'm trying to follow these instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Comment: @Delal, and you're on Linux? Windows? OSX?

Comment: Did you do the install section? Can you try opening up a new Terminal window, and then running `which git` in the new window?

Comment: @Delal, have you already installed Git [from here](http://git-scm.com/download/mac)?

Comment: @Chris, no I installed GitHub for Mac from here: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Comment: @Leigh, I did the install section and when I write the command : which git I don't get any answer.

Comment: You're missing the Command Line tools. If you go into Github->Preferences in the menu line, you can install them in the Advanced tab.

Comment: With [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, you can just install git (and a lot of other software) by typing `brew install git`. This is the method to install git that I'd recommend.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100242/how-can-i-access-the-github-for-mac-command-line-utility-from-the-terminal/13100515#13100515), installing "the command-line tools" from GitHub for Mac only installs a command-line wrapper for GitHub for Mac, not the actual `git` binary.

Comment: I used brew to install it for mine, but I checked in the GitHub for Mac app and it said that it'd install `git` as well as the `github` wrapper. Same as the last comment on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't installed the command-line version of Git; you've only got the graphical GitHub for Mac program.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100515/354577) to a related question suggests installing the command-line version of Git using either Homebrew or [the official Git installer that I linked in the comments before](http://git-scm.com/download/mac).

Once you have done that, you should be able to run `git` on the command-line.

Comment: You are so true, I had mixed Git with Github and I had only downloaded Github. Now I think everyhing is where it supposed to be, so much thanks to you guys here at stack overflow. Again, I am so grateful for your help. Good night.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Git Bash, type

which git

If you're on Windows, this probably shows 
/mingw64/bin/git

Now, please type
cd /mingw64/bin

And then run your command here. e.g.
git config --global user.name "yournamehere"

That's it. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93RvF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this message since you didn't set the Path environment variable to point git.exe.
once you will type git in cmd/git bash you will also get an error.

depends on how you installed the program, but usually the .exe file can be found in C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Answer (score 0):

try to write this command yourself, copy paste might not work.